# Stackoverflow exception when serializing object to JSON

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have a serialization step in my application, however, the object which is being serialized has a circular reference. The Object I am trying to serialize unfortunately isn't in my control, so I can't change it.

When I try to run the application I keep getting a Stackoverflow exception. I've tried some of the suggestions on this forum, but haven't managed to get anywhere.

at the moment Object A is passed into the serializer below, Object A references Object B which references Object A again. I don't need the referenced child Object A, I just need the initial Object A and Object B (if that makes any sense).

```
var jsonFile = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                templatesToDisplay,
                Formatting.Indented,
                new JsonSerializerSettings
                    {
                        PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects,
                        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                    });
```

Any Ideas on how to get passed this?

Thanks
Nav

Comment: Not at a computer with VS but you should be able to specify depth somewhere?

Comment: @Belogix - There's a `MaxDepth` property on the serializer settings but I think it throws if exceeded. Nav, can you just null the reference from Object B to Object A?

Comment: Nope theres no setter on ObjectB within A or from B to A.